# exim produces failed to read delivery status for user

Tags: freebsd, exim, email-server, sa-exim

OS: FreeBSD9 64 Bit

MTA: Exim with SA-Exim, Auth-Radius, Content Scan options

I use exim -v user with default install (without even tweaking anything)

```
LOG: MAIN PANIC
failed to read delivery status for user@localhost.domain.tld from delivery subprocess.
LOG: MAIN PANIC
appendfile transport process returned non zero status 0x0100 exit code 1
```

Can you tell **Why exim is not reading from delivery subprocess**. Is some other process is blocking it ???

ps gives

```
633      v0      ls      0:00:01      login [pam] (login)
641      v0      S       0:00:01      -csh (csh)
662      v0      R+      0:00:00      PS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like the appendfile driver can't write to the destination  mailbox file.

Did you check for permission issues?

Who owns the destination file and containing directories?

Who owns the exim4 binary?

Does it have/needs the sticky bit to be set?

Comment: thank you @alxgomz, there was no read/write permissions on destination, thanks a lot

but will I need to adjust permission for each user (existing/new) in order to trouble shoot this problem.

Comment: but @alxgomz will I need to adjust permission for each user (existing/new) in order to trouble shoot this problem.